I made a simple vim plugin in vimscript
I made a simple plugin for Vim.  I thought it was cool, and I wanted to share it with you. The plugin allows you to create keyboard shortcuts to change themes, is easy to install and simple to configure. This is the code.  I'm keeping the kiss philosophy because I intend to change it to lua in a while as I haven't learned lua yet.
function! ThemeSwitcher(themes, index)
    let themes = a:themes

    " Check if the index is valid
    if a:index < 1 || a:index > len(themes)
        echo "Invalid index. Choose a number between 1 and" . len(themes)
        return
    endif

    
    let theme = themes[a:index - 1]

    " Check if the theme is installed
    if empty(globpath(&runtimepath, 'colors/' . theme . '.vim'))
        echo "Theme " . theme . " not found. Please install it."
        return
    endif

    " Apply the theme
    execute 'colorscheme ' . theme
    echo "Theme " . theme . " applied."
endfunction

function! MapThemeSwitcherKeys(themes)
    for i in range(1, len(a:themes))
        " Map keys to switch between themes
        execute 'nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t' . i . ' :call ThemeSwitcher(' . string(a:themes) . ', ' . i .')<CR>'  
        endfor
endfunction

To use it is very simple, just download the code with the installer from my github repository gardenal plugin Once installed you just need to add code like this to your configuration file:
source ~/.vim/plugins/gardenal.vim

let themes = ['desert', 'gruvbox', 'monokai']
call MapThemeSwitcherKeys(themes)
nnoremap <silent> 1 :call ThemeSwitcher(themes, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> 2 :call ThemeSwitcher(themes, 2)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> 3 :call ThemeSwitcher(themes, 3)<CR>

I hope you like it!
